# Method Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception

Edit: Exception error I'm getting when trying to call parent method, which never happened to me before.

I'm calling a function in other class to retrieve `ItemSet` from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll`

**Calling part in `c#`:**

```
ItemSet itemsSet  = GetItemSet(variable1, variable2);
string stringSet = GetStringSet(variable1, variable2);
```

**Methods in `vb.net`:**

```
Public Function GetStringSet(ByVal variable1 As String, ByVal variable2 As String) As String
    Return variable1 + variable2
End Function
```

'below method is trowing exception

```
Public Function GetItemSet(ByVal variable1 As String, ByVal variable2 As String) As ItemSet
    Dim items As ItemSet = somelocal function to get ItemSet which works
    Return items
End Function
```

1. `Bin` folder has been `cleaned`.
2. `Cleaned` and `rebuild` multiple times.
3. `String function` was added later to check if by any chance older version of `dll` was being used.
4. String one works nicely, where with this `ItemSet itemsSet = GetItemSet(variable1, variable2);` uncommented I can't even get into parent method.

Any ideas why this may occur?

Comment: Note: your second example function in `vb.net` is not `vb.net` that is `C#`... Example `ItemSet items = somelocal`

Comment: `Dim itemsSet As ItemSet = GetItemSet(variable1, variable2);` that is wrong for `C#`... are you getting these confused? Also you are missing the function names.

Comment: C#?, that's not C#, you've mixed VB.Net and C# syntax. Show the real, unmodified code and a C# translation if you want.

Comment: @Claudius turn on `Option Strict`...

Comment: `Dim itemsSet As ItemSet = GetItemSet(variable1, variable2);` that is **not** `C#`...

Comment: The "cailling part in C#" is mixed vb and C#. I didn't downvoted, but seems clear the reasons why someone could downvote this, please, organize the code that you are showing us! and complete the missing return value...

Comment: @ElektroStudios I tried to explain that, but OP is telling us to read and it's in `vb`. I beg to differ...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared functions correctly please try following functions

```
Public Function GetStringSet(ByVal variable1 As String, ByVal variable2 As String) As String
    Return variable1 & variable2
End Function

Public Function GetItemSet(ByVal variable1 As String, ByVal variable2 As String) As ItemSet
    Dim items As ItemSet = somelocal function to get ItemSet which works
    Return items
End Function
```

Comment: Thank for noticing but they are properly declared.